# Access S3 files on cloud

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am quite new to AmazonCloud. I set up an EC2 instance to be able to run my jupyter notebooks on cloud and I am now trying to set up my data files in order to be able to access them everywhere.

My goal would be like I do on localhost to open data in my notebook such as CSV or Json Files that are located on the cloud using Amazon S3

I open up a Amazon S3 Bucket where I uploaded my Data, I set up my bucket settings to Block public access > Disable

However when I try to access my data using the url :https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/file.json

I get the error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>92D39BE8B6594380</RequestId>
<HostId>
C0H9RwlhzCxSdp2nLh5o+G7XWSKn3aES1YWzWgbv3tQL6B18Ky0JDkGE0Psn43c3Wl1jiYr9rng=
</HostId>
```

Any idea how could I access it  ?

Comment: Could you please show us the relevant parts of your code so far?

Comment: Did you made the object public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a IAM role to allow your EC2 instance to have access to S3. The role is created in the IAM section of the AWS console. The trusted entity is EC2 and the policy attached could be "AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess" that looks like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "s3:Get*",
      "s3:List*"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"
  }]
}
```

For the connection from a Jupiter Notebook to S3 you can use boto3.
More information here: [Using an IAM Role to Grant Permissions to Applications Running on Amazon EC2 Instances - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html)